# inputStyleClass PrimeNg Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I want show hide class "has-error" by boolean variable for input of `<p-calendar>` on PrimeNg Angular 2 with properties **inputStyleClass**

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="fromDate" [showIcon]="true" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" styleClass="datepicker" inputStyleClass="has-error" pTooltip = "From Date less than To Date" tooltipPosition="top" [tooltipDisabled]="isValidFromDate" (keydown)="keydownSearch($event)"></p-calendar>
```

I tried set inputStyleClass="has-error: isHasError" with isHasError is true || false but it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="fromDate" [showIcon]="true" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" styleClass="datepicker" inputStyleClass="(validate == false) ? 'has-error' : ''" pTooltip = "From Date less than To Date" tooltipPosition="top" [tooltipDisabled]="isValidFromDate" (keydown)="keydownSearch($event)"></p-calendar>
```