# Cannot get inputStyleClass to work at all

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using `<p-calendar>` in one of my components. I am trying to style it using a class in my sass-file, but `inputStyleClass` does not have any effect at all. In fact, I can't even see the class in the styles of Chromes DevTools. It is however shown as an attribute of the `<input>` element (`ng-reflect-klass="calendar-input"`).

I have read all I could find (e.g. [inputStyleClass PrimeNg Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444338/inputstyleclass-primeng-angular-2)) and tried doing things accordingly.

These are reduced examples of the relevant files:

### Does not work:

**time-edit.component.html**

```
<p-calendar [inputStyleClass]="'calendar-input'"></p-calendar>
```

**time-edit.component.sass**

```
.calendar-input
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442 !important
```

### Works:

**time-edit.component.html**

```
<p-calendar [inputStyle]="{'border-left': '5px solid #a94442'}"></p-calendar>
```

However, I do not want to style it this way.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't my class from the sass file be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to angular's [`ViewEncapsulation`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) which is set to `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` by default.
In order to style a child component style you have the following options:

1. Use [`ViewEncapsulation.None`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#None)
2. Use a global style
3. Use `::ng-deep`, note this is not recommended since it is [mareked as deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

You can see a working example with `ViewEncapsulation.None` in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxpnvu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hate angulars documentation. I can't ever seem to find a complete answer there.